# SPA/WEBAPI2 site picking up servername and not username

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api2

I've published my SPA site on the intranet but it's not picking up the users Windows AD account. When I run the app in VS2012 it picks up my user name fine however, when I open the site via my browser and run a URL to the API i get this message (generated by my controller)

```
string user = System.Environment.UserName; //(user being: OURDOMAIN\\WEBSERVERNAME$)
```

**and in the returned JSON...**

'Result':'Failed to do check: Login failed for user 'OURDOMAIN\WEBSERVERNAME$'

This is a DB message (as OURDOMAIN\WEBSERVERNAME$ isn't a DB user), the problem I have is that I want it to pick up the windows AD user, not the server name.
Windows Auth is enabled on IIS and everything else disabled.

Many thanks for any help.

itsdanny

Comment: Hi Danny, Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: It might have been to do with Firefox, needing enabling for AD. Or it needed an Authorized tag on the class. will have to check the code